# Sublime Text 3 can't compile ruby

Tags: ruby, build, sublimetext3

When I make a ruby file in Sublime Text 3 Beta (I downloaded it from here http://www.sublimetext.com/3) and I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to build it doesn't show anything. My ruby file is this one:

```
3.times { puts "Hello World" }
```

I checked my Ruby.sublime-build I found this:

```
"cmd": ["ruby", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.ruby"
```

How can I make Sublime Text 3 Beta to build Ruby files? My computer SO is Windows 10 x64 and I have installed ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]. Also, the environment variable of ruby is in PATH: `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin`.

Comment: What is your file named?

Comment: When I ruby -v in the console it appears: ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32] like my post. My file name is beginning.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Saving the file before building it in Sublime Text resolved it.

1. Save File
2. ctrl + B to build
3. Output appears in the build window

Comment: For me, going `ctrl+shift+b` and selecting Ruby (from 'Ruby' and 'Python') was the solution.